# Error Loading Minecraft World when using MoCreatures, Realistic World Gen, and CustomMobSpawner

Tags: minecraft

Using:
 - Minecraft 1.7.10
 - Forge 10.13.4.1614
 - [Mod] Dr. Zhark's Mo Creatures (not enough rep to post link)
 - [Mod] Realistic World Generator (RWG) [2](http://mod-minecraft.net/realistic-world-gen-mod/)
 - [Mod] Dr. Zhark's Custom mob Spawner (CMS) (not enough rep to post link)

I attempted to modify the config files in the .minecraft folder to add all of the RWG Biomes to the acceptable spawn locations for the MoCreatures mod via CMS. I modified the EntityBiomeGroups.cfg file found at
C:...\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\config\CustomSpawner\overworld

And just for an example of the code used in the file:

```
S:MOC_MEDIUMFISH_DEFAULT <RWG|rwg_oceanIce:RWG|rwg_oceanCold:RWG|rwg_oceanTemperate:RWG|rwg_oceanHot:RWG|rwg_oceanWet:RWG|rwg_oceanOasis:MC|Swampland:MC|MushroomIslandShore:MC|Beach:MC|Stone Beach:MC|Cold Beach:MC|Swampland M>
```

After modifying the file, and checking multiple times to ensure that everything was typed in correctly, I received this error while attempting to load any minecraft world:

```
    Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954)
    at drzhark.customspawner.utils.CMSUtils.parseName(CMSUtils.java:63)
    at drzhark.customspawner.environment.EnvironmentSettings.populateSpawnBiomes(EnvironmentSettings.java:732)
    at drzhark.customspawner.environment.EnvironmentSettings.updateSettings(EnvironmentSettings.java:259)
    at drzhark.customspawner.utils.CMSUtils.addWorldEnvironment(CMSUtils.java:128)
    at drzhark.customspawner.EventHooks.onWorldLoad(EventHooks.java:175)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_156_EventHooks_onWorldLoad_Load.invoke(.dynamic)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:54)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:140)
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71247_a(IntegratedServer.java:73)
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71197_b(IntegratedServer.java:92)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:387)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer$2.run(MinecraftServer.java:685)
```

I do not understand this completely. Does it help me find where the error is? Can anybody read this and tell me where I can find it? I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score -2):

May be this mod download is error,
you try reinstall this mod - [download here](http://niceminecraft.net/realistic-world-gen-mod/)